# Is there an ivy/ant equivalent to mvn jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: ant, maven, packaging, ivy, dependency-management

With `maven-assembly-plugin` it's possible to package a project into a single jar w all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it by myself, but [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) seems to do what you need. It also has an [ant task](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=ant) and offers an [ant example.](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=build-tools&file=ant-example)